# Can’t click/drag MacOS notifications, which are transparent, have to restart Notification Centre

Tags: mojave, notifications

I have this problem on macOS Mojave (10.14.3, but it happened on older versions too)

Notifications are transparent and non-responsive to click/drag anything.

See screenshot:

[image: transparent_notification.png]

If I kill NotificationCentre process it disappears or become "top-positioned" element on display so I can drag / click it like I normally would.

This usually happens if I disconnect my external display or wake from sleep.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

The only fix officially is to kill the notification center in Terminal with

```
killall NotificationCenter
```

This may become inconvenient if you need to do it too often though.

Comment: yeah, i do that now but its annoying, guess i have to reinstall

Comment: it wont help it is just buggy as fck .. I guess some app is bugging the notifications but I was not able to find which one.

Comment: Sometimes just Lock & Unlock helps. I thought Spectacle could cause this, but it didn’t so.. i dunno

Comment: I was not having Spectacle and it was still happening. However I have MAGNET ... which basically do the same (for a price..) hmm I will try to kill them both to see but I doubt I also have OverSight... but also I doubt it is because of ti ... will try to kill the 3 to see

Comment: Some Apple KB article would be helpful, but.. we know Apple

Comment: there is no reason Apple can't fix a shit :) they are not a company fixing things they just make new things ;)